# How to center element vertically

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In the code above, I'm trying to center the `h1` element over the image both both vertically and horizontally using just `bootstrap 4` without any css styling. **how to do that?**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="navbar" class="p-2">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="BR Architects"><span id="BR">BR</span> Architects</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>         
    </div>

    <div id="header-img">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <img class="card-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/architect.jpg" alt="Card image">
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <h1 class="card-title"><span class="text-white">BR</span> Architects</h1>   
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

*Thanks!*

Comment: methods explained in that link doesn't work for me, see the edited code above

Comment: in the css I've set html and body height to 100% and i try many of methods and all doesn't work

Comment: The other questions both explain that the content of the parent element, `card-img-overlay` can be centered with flexbox https://www.codeply.com/go/QqSKdFp36M

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I could think of at the moment

Add this line inside your `card-img-overlay`   " `d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center` "

Example:

```
<div class="card-img-overlay d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
       <h1 class="card-title "><span class="text-white">BR</span> Architects</h1>   
 </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add `d-flex` class to `card-img-overlay` and then apply the classes [justify-content-center](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content) for horizontal alignment and [align-items-center](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#align-items) for vertical alignment.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="header-img">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/architect.jpg" alt="Card image">
    <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <h1 class="card-title">
        <span class="text-white">BR</span> Architects
      </h1>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="header-img">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <img class="card-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/architect.jpg" alt="Card image">
           <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <h1 class="card-title"><span class="text-white">BR</span> Architects</h1>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `row` should only be used to contain columns. for flexbox just use `d-flex`